# Colour scatter plot by column Plotly

Tags: python, matplotlib, colors, plotly, scatter-plot

I would like to create a scatter plot with 3 variables: `Age`, `Value` and `City`. How can I colour the plot by `City`?

Current output is a simple scatter plot of `Value` against `Age`:
[image]

Current Code:

```
import datetime
import plotly.offline as py
import plotly
import plotly.graph_objects as go
fig = go.Figure()

fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x= data1['Age'], y = data1['Value'], mode='markers', name='lines+markers'))
fig.show()
```

---

Update:

Tried:

```
import plotly.express as px

fig = px.scatter(data1, x=data1['Age'], y=data1['Value'], color=data1['City']) 
fig.show()
```

and caught error:

```
KeyError: (nan, '', '', '', '')
```

---

Update:

`Age` and `Value` have been cleaned. Here are some unique values for `City`(sorry to change the column). There are some messy figures.

```
       ['NT', 'WAIKATO', 'VICTORIA', 'South Australia', 'OTHER', 'ON',
       'Nsw', 'IL', 'MD - MARYLAND', 'ABU DHABI', 'VIENNA', 'TX',
       'VILKAVISKIS', 'NY', 'BALEARES', 'UK', 'GLOUCESTERSHIRE',
       'LA MANCHE', 'TEXAS', 'DUBAI', 'ENGLAND', 'ITALY', nan,
       'GREATER LONDON', 'BEDFORDSHIRE', 'HEREFORDSHIRE',
       'BADEN-WÃ?RTTEMBERG', 'Australian Capital Territory',
       'ABERDEENSHIRE', 'OXFORDSHIRE', 'LONDON', 'BC', 'SK',
       'NOORD-HOLLAND', 'UNITED KINGDOM', 'New South Wales', 'Brookdale',
       'Western Australia', 'GALWAY', 'Queensland', 'TOKYO',
       'HAUTE-GARONNE', 'WORCESTERSHIRE', 'CALIFORNIA', 'JAPAN',
       'NORTHUMBERLAND', 'NJ - NEW JERSEY', 'GLOS', 'DORSET', 'TENNESSEE',
       'BANGKOK', 'CANTERBURY', 'WEXFORD', 'MIDDLESEX', 'SURREY', 'MI',
       'NEVADA', 'KENTUCKY', 'NEW YORK', 'ZUID-HOLLAND', 'HONG KONG',
       'ESSEX', 'FL', 'LILLEHAMMER', 'DEVON', 'NEW TERRITORIES', 'KENT',
       'THAILAND', 'Pyrmont', 'SINGAPORE', 'FRIBOURG', 'CAIRO',
       'QUEENSLAND', 'HAMPSHIRE', 'NEW JERSEY', 'WEST MIDLANDS',
       'MICHIGAN', 'NONE', 'WI', 'BARNET', 'STAFFS', 'WARWICKSHIRE'...]
```

Comment: Please, could you report a part of your data in order to understand how the dataframe `data1` is organized and if there are missing / strange values in the column `'Continent'`?

Comment: @AndreaBlengino I think the issue is due to the messy data in the third column. Theoretically, if I convert all data to string, will it work?

Comment: @AndreaBlengino FYI I tried `Gender` instead of `City` and it worked. I think it's my problem, should've cleaned the city column.

Comment: @nilsinelabore if the answer helped you please consider to upvote it too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside the `go.Scatter` definition you should specify the `color` parameter as `color=data1['Continent']`. See the [Plotly documentation](https://plotly.com/python/line-and-scatter/) for more information.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Could you please  take a look at the error returned in edited question?

Comment: Can it be caused by too many unique values in the column? I actually used `city` instead of `continent` and there are around 380 of them.

Comment: OP says they tried this without success